# Prove: $\nabla_w((\textbf{w}^T\textbf{x})^2) = 2\textbf{w}^T\textbf{x}\textbf{x}^T$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

Consider the following two $\mathbb{R}^n$ vectors **w** = $[w_0, w_1, ... , w_{n-1}]$, **x** = $[x_0, x_1, ..., x_{n-1}]^T$.

I proved that $\nabla_w(\textbf{w}^T\textbf{x}) = \textbf{x}$.

I also proved that $\nabla_w((\textbf{w}^T\textbf{x})^2) = 2\textbf{x}\textbf{w}^T\textbf{x}$.

Now I need to prove that $\nabla_w((\textbf{w}^T\textbf{x})^2) = 2\textbf{w}^T\textbf{x}\textbf{x}^T$.

I've tried solving this for quite a while to no avail.
Would really appreciate some help here.

Comment: Is there a typo?  I don't see any difference between $\nabla_w((\textbf{w}^T\textbf{x})^2)$ and $\nabla_w((\textbf{w}^T\textbf{x})^2)$ ...

Comment: That’s not a typo, they wanted me to prove that the same gradient is equal to both of these.

Comment: I do not understand.  The first one is a multiple of $x$, the second one a multiple of $x^T$.

Comment: The professor just admitted that there is in fact a typo. Sorry about that!